# How to stop program until a button is pressed in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

How do I make it so that the program doesn't keep reading in code until the button is clicked?

Why?: I have a 10x10 grid with buttons in each part and then code running depending on what is clicked.  However, my program keeps reading in code so there is never a choice being made and it gives me error.  I tried giving it a infinite loop until a button is pressed, but that doesn't work out so well

-edit
I'm a complete beginner with Java.

This is a picture of the GUI

[image: GUI]

http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img843/5351/sascp.png

What I want is for the code to not keep running step by step until I click a button.

E.G.:

- create gameGUI
- wait until and check which button is pressed

---

```
if(buttonClicked[i][k] == something){
  System.out.println("lool");
}
```

But what's happening in my code is that it creates the `gameGUI` and then because the user isn't fast enough to click it just skips over the if statement or gets a run-time error because nothing was pressed.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post some code samples and/or exceptions you get.

Comment: What flavor of Java are you talking about? Java has no "buttons", outside the context of some GUI. Is this Android? Swing? J2ME? You need to be more specific as to what you're talking about.

Comment: *"reading in code"*  What does that mean, exactly?  In both Android & Swing (& I'd expect J2ME), buttons fire events when told to do so (by activating them).  You would generally just wait for that to happen before doing anything, and not bother with what the rest of the GUI is doing (or not doing) at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Android & Swing (& I'd expect J2ME), buttons fire events when told to do so (by activating them). You would generally just wait for that to happen before doing anything, and not bother with what the rest of the GUI is doing (or not doing) at the time.

Or in other words:

- Add an `ActionListener` to the buttons.
- In the `actionPerformed()` method, insert the code that you have above.

### Also

- The code snippet provides almost no useful information.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
- That GUI looks like Swing to me.  If it is not, then what is it?
- Please always copy/paste run-time errors.

Comment: thank youuu!!!! 
That is the most helpful thing anyone has told me.

Everyone was just telling me negative things, that i made no sense. 

But i just didn't understand.

Thank you again Andrew, your thing makes alot more sense.


However, another question for you. 
what would I do about the first player and second player?

Comment: Please criticize, I always like positive criticism. Suggest ways of making improvements, removing things. Like i said, i'm not the best java coder. I work more in C programming. Also for the pictures, just use a small icon. mine is 70x70 pastebin.com/pj3q5Fru - game.java (main) pastebin.com/yRFEHUZb - graphics.java pastebin.com/KFD75VFx - queueItem.java – Kelsey Abreu

Comment: My actionPerformed() is in graphics

Comment: okay, i'll go read what it is. Sorry for the complexity. I'm new to this site and to java. Two double negative